# SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutRequest. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-app-engine

I Created a Google Cloud Module in Android Studio as the backend. Now I am trying to run the test locally using [this](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/run_test_deploy) guide. Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
ment.agent.impl.Transformer transform
SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutRequest. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(MethodVisitor.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:959)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:693)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.rewrite(Transformer.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:113)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.<init>(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:153)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactoryImpl.getAsyncDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceFactoryImpl.java:20)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactoryImpl.getDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceFactoryImpl.java:13)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceFactory.java:20)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(DatastoreServiceFactory.java:40)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.getDatastoreService(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:86)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.init(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:36)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:271)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ManualInstanceHolder.startUp(ManualInstanceHolder.java:77)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:262)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:225)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Note: I can access the page on http://localhost:8080/ but I am not sure what this error exactly means.